# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react components and react-router-dom's Route, however importing {Route} from react-router-dom fails with error: -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Here is the line which trigger the error as shown by react error default page. 
[image]

```py
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                <div>
                    <h1>Home Page</h1>
                </div>
            )
            } />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the stack trace that's an error with Express not React router. Are you fetching any data from api or have a server running?

Comment: Your post is misleading I tryied the same code on codeSandbox, and it is working  with minor change, see: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-feather-dxwy1, can you add a codesandbox? This might not be related to react-router or react

Comment: Issue is seems to be from backend only and not frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your Route within Router.

So, import the router:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
```

And add that to your class:

```
class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                <div>
                    <h1>Home Page</h1>
                </div>
            )
            } />
        </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vince, I just checked the source again and realized that I made a mistake while importing and I couldn't see it yesterday, this solution actually worked. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Remove this line....from actions or somewhere

```
import { response } from "express"; //  generated from Intellisense...
```

Answer (score 5):

in my case it was the following line messing with my code . it was added because of auto-import when i was trying to read e.target.value .

```
import e from 'express'
```

i removed it and it works again!

Answer (score 3):

When you handle the response in the backend sometimes Vs Code automatically imports a package called the response from express. Do a global search on ( response } and remove that auto imported line

Answer (score 0):

Weird but this is how it is. Some of the `express` modules are imported automatically which causes this problem mainly.

In my case it was `import { json } from "express";` for others it may be `response` etc.